# Adjust Hrizontal Linear Layout with three textview and weight in Android

Tags: android

3 things to remember:

set the android:layout_width of the children to "0dp"

set the android:weightSum of the parent (edit: as Jason Moore noticed, this attribute is optional, because by default it is set to the children's layout_weight sum)

set the android:layout_weight of each child proportionally 
(e.g. weightSum="5", three children: layout_weight="1", layout_weight="3", layout_weight="1")

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="3" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @ Rajesh kumar What do you want please describe..?

Comment: I want to show three text view / buttons in horizontal position.that three text view / buttons supports for all kind of devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rajesh Kumar you can try to this code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="Btn 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".60"
        android:text="Btn 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="Btn 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```